# image with 3 possibility of value

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I would like to personalize the 3rd columns to contain QCheckBox widgets. I would like those QCheckBox widgets to be customized with three icons: 1.png (Default state) | 2.png (Selected state) | 3.png (Disabled state). So  I could do this using a custom delegate with the following implementation:

```
#include "mydelegate.h"
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyleOptionViewItem>


MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject* parent) :
QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
// 1.png
_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("1.png"), QIcon::Active, QIcon::On);
// 2.png
_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("2.png"), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);
// 3.png
_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("3.png"), QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::On);
}

void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& 
option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
if (index.column() != 2)
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
else
{
    bool value = index.model()->data(index, 
Qt::UserRole).toBool();
    QStyleOptionButton buttonVis;
    buttonVis.rect = option.rect;
    buttonVis.iconSize = QSize(50, 50);
    buttonVis.icon = _icon;
    buttonVis.features |= QStyleOptionButton::Flat;
    buttonVis.state |= value ? QStyle::State_Enabled : QStyle::State_None;
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &buttonVis, painter);
}
}

bool MyDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent* event, QAbstractItemModel* model, 
const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index)
{
if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
{
    bool value = model->data(index, Qt::UserRole).toBool();
    model->setData(index, !value, Qt::UserRole);
}
return true;
}
```

The problem that it's work for 1.png and 3.png and not for the 2.png. i want that it will work for the three icons

Comment: And where is the question / problem?

Comment: it's work for 1.png and 3.png and not for the 2.png

Comment: it work for active state and disable state and not for selected state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to implement the paint(...) or use editorEvent(...) methods, it is only necessary to override the initStyleOption(...) method by enabling the option of the icon.

In the following example the item (2, 2) is selected, the item (4, 2) is disabled and the other items are enabled but not selected showing 3 types of icons:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    MyDelegate(QObject *parent=nullptr):
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
    {
        m_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("1.png"), QIcon::Active, QIcon::On);
        m_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("2.png"), QIcon::Selected, QIcon::On);
        m_icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("3.png"), QIcon::Disabled, QIcon::On);
    }
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        if (index.column() == 2){
            option->features |= QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDecoration;
            option->icon = m_icon;
            option->decorationSize = QSize(50, 50);
        }
    }
private:
    QIcon m_icon;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget w(10, 4);
    MyDelegate *delegate = new MyDelegate(&w);
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate);
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    w.setItem(4, 2, item);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

**Update:** The OP is using an inadequate terminology since it refers to the status of a widget (normal, selected, disabled), instead it must indicate the states unchecked, partially checked and checked.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    MyDelegate(QObject *parent=nullptr):
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
    {
        uncheckedIcon = QIcon("1.png");
        partiallyCheckedIcon = QIcon("2.png");
        checkedIcon = QIcon("3.png");
    }
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        if (index.column() == 2){
            QIcon m_icon;
            QVariant value = index.data(Qt::UserRole);
            Qt::CheckState state = static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(value.toInt());
            if(state == Qt::Unchecked)
                option->icon = uncheckedIcon;
            else if (state == Qt::PartiallyChecked)
                option->icon = partiallyCheckedIcon;
            else
                option->icon = checkedIcon;
            option->features |= QStyleOptionViewItem::HasDecoration;
            option->decorationSize = QSize(50, 50);
        }
    }
    bool editorEvent(QEvent* event, QAbstractItemModel* model,
                     const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) override
    {
        bool r = QStyledItemDelegate::editorEvent(event, model, option, index);
        if(index.column() != 2)
            return r;
        if ((event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
                || (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
                || (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)) {
            if ((event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
                    || (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick))
                return true;
            QVariant value = index.data(Qt::UserRole);
            Qt::CheckState state = static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(value.toInt());
            state = static_cast<Qt::CheckState>((state + 1) % 3);
            return model->setData(index, state, Qt::UserRole);
        }
        return r;
    }
private:
    QIcon uncheckedIcon;
    QIcon partiallyCheckedIcon;
    QIcon checkedIcon;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget w(10, 4);
    MyDelegate *delegate = new MyDelegate(&w);
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate);
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the answer that i need it. i need to change the icon by click. When i click on the icon it's will change for example : 1.png -> 2.png and from 2.png -> 3.png and from 3.png to 1.png it's like QCheckBox with 3 states

Comment: @user6223604 Well, your terminology is incorrect since the states of an icon are not the status of a checkbox. in a checkbox it has the states unchecked, checked partially and checked.

Comment: So you think to change the terminology to QLabel for example or how ? I need just to change the image by click

Comment: @user6223604 Check the states of QIcon in the docs, the QLabel does not have 3 states, it only has 2 states: normal and disabled. QLabel does not support the selected state. The normal state is when it is not selected or disabled. With your explanation it is clearer what you want, perhaps an issue to your question clarify those details.